# make objects push against each other in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

me again with a very specific question about [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) . What I would like to do is, that rectangles push against each other. Lets say I have following situation that each rectangle is side by side [example picture](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/i01kxxrs/thumb/Bildschirmfoto20131017um19.03.48.png) and I let the one in the middle transform big:

```
r.click(function() { r.animate({ width: 100, height: 100 }, 500); });
```

how can I handle it, that the other ones move correctly away like the transformation.
I've tried it by transforming every by hand, but the problem is, my markup isnt that simple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you are after, can you try reexplaining, what you want to happen to the middle block, and what do you want to happen to the outer blocks. Do you mean you want every block to move the same ? Or the outer blocks moving away like an explosion or something ?

Comment: @Ian thanks for your reply. I've made another picture, after the transformation. What I intend to do is, that the transformation moves the other shapes away. http://i.imagebanana.com/img/8lvg1kwc/Bildschirmfoto20131017um19.03.48.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to know a specific answer without seeing any code and knowing what the markup issues or or how you can tie some maths into calculating the figures, it will likely be more complicated, but you may be able to calculate the amount moved by the rects compared to the new width of the original rect. This shows an example of one way you could maybe approach it... jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/R8avm/3/ 
Edit: There's an updated fiddle which has some basic maths which can sort of figure the end x,y if you know which direction the cubes will be in. http://jsfiddle.net/R8avm/4/ It will need more complex stuff for more rects moving at different angles if thats needed.

```
<div id="container"></div>

paper = Raphael( "container",400,400);
var rects = [ [ 100,50,50,50, 150,50 ],  //x,y,w,h,newx,newy
          [ 50,100,50,50,  50,150 ],
          [ 50,0,50,50, 50, -50 ],
          [ 0,50,50,50, -50,50 ],
        ];  

var newRects = new Array(4);           

var r = paper.rect(50,50,50,50).attr({ fill: '#123' });

for (var a=0; a<rects.length; a++) {
         newRects[a] = paper.rect( rects[a][0], rects[a][1], rects[a][2], rects[a][3]);
};

r.click(function() { 
   r.animate({ width: 150, height: 150, x: 0, y: 0 }, 500);               
         for (var a=0; a<rects.length; a++) {
             newRects[a].animate({ x: rects[a][4] , y: rects[a][5]   }, 500);
        };

});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. I'm not that good into calculating math stuff, so I need a lil bit time to work me through this! But anyways I think it would be very useful if I show you at a live example what I intend to do. http://jobs.super-sized.de/web_try/ When you hover over the text at the top-left you see the squares forming a shape, and if I press one specific "square" they're about to move away and one gets bigger!